# Firefox layout issues with simple-marquee js library

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I've implemented the simple-marquee plugin: https://github.com/conradfeyt/Simple-Marquee

It's working as expected on Safari and Chrome, but I'm having issues with how it displayed on Firefox. It's messing with layout on the page its on: [deannoble.com.au](https://deannoble.com.au)

**Here is the html**

```
    <div class="marquee">
        <ul class="marquee-content-items">
            <li>Web Designer</li>
            <li>Bread baker</li>
            <li>From Melbourne</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Here is part of the css I think might be causing the issue:**

```
.simple-marquee-container *{
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

**The JS is**

```
$('.simple-marquee-container').SimpleMarquee();
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After doing some further digging, I worked out that Firefox doesn't like `display:inline-block;`. Changing it to `display:block` solved the issue.